# Implementing an interface not working

Tags: java

```
public class TestImpl {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelloImpl h1 = new HelloImpl(), h2 = h1;
        h1.message = "holla";
        System.out.println(h2.sayHello());
    }
}

interface Hello {
    String sayHello();
}

class HelloImpl implements Hello {
    static String message = "Hello";

    String sayHello() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

I get "attempting to assign weaker privilegies."

Comment: Make `sayHello` `public` in `HelloImpl`.

Comment: Can you tell me why, please?

Comment: It  is also a good idea to use the `@override` annotation preceding methods that override other methods.

Comment: Take a look at [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Comment: If you are interested in why in most cases methods declared in interface don't have `public` modifier take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161633/should-methods-in-a-java-interface-be-declared-with-or-without-a-public-access-m).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In an `interface` all members are `public` by default.

You cannot implement (or override) a method and assign weaker privileges as this would not allow polymorphism.

You must make `sayHello()` `public`.

```
class HelloImpl implements Hello {
    private static final String message = "Hello";

    public String sayHello() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Also, internal constants should be `private final`

Comment: So, I need to explicitly say that my method is public?

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc yes, why would it be otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

"All abstract, default, and static methods in an interface are implicitly public, so you can omit the public modifier."
from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceDef.html

Your interface's method is implicitly public but the implementing class method is not