# java8 Interface allowing public default method

Tags: java, java-8, access-modifiers, default-method

In java 8 default method implementation can take both `public` and `default` modifier.
What is the main difference between below two methods. Under which conditions which type need to follow.

```
default int makeMul(int x, int y) {
    return x * y;
}

public default int makeMul(int x, int y) {
    return x * y;
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161633/should-methods-in-a-java-interface-be-declared-with-or-without-a-public-access-m

Answer (score 9):

There's nothing special about default methods here. Java has always allowed interface methods to be declared public, even though they're already implicitly public.

From [JLS 9.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4):

> Every method declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly public (§6.6). It is permitted, but discouraged as a matter of style, to redundantly specify the public modifier for a method declaration in an interface.

Answer (score 3):

As the others suggested, the `default` keyword has two main uses:

- Prior to Java 8, it can only be employed to trigger the default case in a `switch-case` statement.
- From Java 8 onwards, developers are allowed to provide implemented methods inside interfaces (which previously wasn't possible), with the use of the `default` keyword at the method's declaration (`public default int method()`).

As far as I understand, using the `default` keyword at a method's declaration when in a *simple class*, does not make any difference at all.

For an extensive discussion on the purpose of `default` methods in interfaces, see [Purpose of Default or Defender methods in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998309/purpose-of-default-or-defender-methods-in-java-8)