# Tool to strip public method modifier from java source files?

Tags: java, interface, access-modifiers, tooling

Is there any tool out there that can remove/strip/delete the "public" modifier on Java interface method declarations?

Thanks!

Comment: your IDE + regex may be enough for your use case.

Comment: Just curious: What's the point? They are still public.

Comment: @Andreas, I think that [*is* the point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161633/should-methods-in-a-java-interface-be-declared-with-or-without-a-public-access-m).

Comment: IntellijJ will do it easily.  Get a better IDE.

Comment: IntelliJ: Analyze / Run Inspection by Name / search for "Unnecessary interface modifier" / Fix All

Comment: Tried IntelliJ (latest).. Unnecessary interface modifier apparently some of our Java 8 interfaces holding static and default methods. I'm not used to IntelliJ, so maybe this is a config/user issue.. though you'd expect the tool to detect project JDK versions..

Comment: .. apparently [breaks] some of...