# Why, after compiling an interface, "default" method modifier is gone from "javap -v"?

Tags: java, default-method, javap

I have observed, that after compiling an interface containing `default` method definition, like:

```java
interface Delta {

    default void someMethod() {
        System.out.println("Hi.");
    }

}
```

and after disassembling the respective `.class` file (including only corresponding snippet here):

```java
javap -v Delta.class

####

{
  public void someMethod();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: (0x0001) ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: getstatic     #1                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
         3: ldc           #2                  // String Hi.
         5: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
         8: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 10: 0
        line 11: 8
}
```

`default` modifier is gone.

Could anyone explain - why?

I am running:

```
openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)
```

<sub>Note, that I am aware, that all methods are implicitly `public`, when no modifier is defined. So, I am [not asking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54553041/java-9-interface-why-default-modifier-converted-into-public-modifier) *why* `public` modifier is present in the compiled version of the file.</sub>

Comment: what java version, obviously. might be a bug in `javap` - since I am on jdk-16 and I do see it.

Comment: @Eugene good point. It's `openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15`.

Comment: The question is really why `javap` doesn't show the `default` modifier. The modifier itself is source code, not bytecode, so it wouldn't be literally present in the compiled bytecode (and the fact that the method isn't marked as `abstract` is enough to know it has a default implementation).

Comment: @kaya3 then why all other modifiers are present in the disassembled one? I would really appreciate if you could just try to help me understand my point, without just rushing into demonstrating *how wrong my question is*.

Comment: eh, sorry, don't have the same exact version, but on a higher 11 (`11.0.9.1`), I see it. On Mac, btw.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri I did read your question, and I'm telling you this is to do with how `javap` produces its output, not to do with what is or isn't present in the compiled `.class` file. But I don't have an answer for why `javap` doesn't print the word `default` in its output, so that is the question needing an answer.

Comment: [this?](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8235200)

Comment: @kaya3 well, that's all my question is about - why `default` is missing; however, I can't be sure, that it's due to `javap` and `javac`.. or maybe I should be sure?

Comment: Yes, I got that, and I'm telling you that I am sure `javap` is responsible for this, not `javac`.

Comment: @kaya3 I see. Thanks.

Comment: @Eugene looks interesting.. so, it seems to be a `javap 11.0.2` bug then.

Comment: Note that methods are not generally implicitly public; rather, _all members_ of an interface are public.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- wrong. You can define `private` instance method. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surely looks like a `javap` bug, see [this defect](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8235200). I've encountered a few more of these `javap` issues when new features where added, just FYI.

Comment: Upvoted; one catch though: "Affected versions: 8, 11.0.1, 12". They probably had it in the 11.0.2 as well.

Comment: So, they've just included where it was fixed.. but not all the versions where it was present. :)